# Azure Data Factory, how to supply pipeline schedule date as value to activities

Tags: azure-data-factory, u-sql

I previously had a Pipeline parameter of **LookBack** with a static default value of **-1**
Then in the child Pipelines/Activities had that translated into

```
@adddays(utcnow(), pipeline().parameters.lookback)
```

Where that would take today, subtrack the -1 to give you a date which is then supplied to the U-SQL script.

This creates problems when we're reprocessing/back processing and that processing time crosses over the UTC time, jumping ahead 1 day.

To make the scheduling more robust, I've adjusted the Top level pipeline to take in a DateTime field of type string, which is passed to the child pipelines/activities and onto the scripts for an explicit schedule.

```
@pipeline().parameters.processDate
```

The top level pipeline is on a standard schedule which runs each day at around 5am.  How do I pass that schedule DateTime to the top level pipeline when the pipeline parameters doesn't offer the dynamic values, but only a static default value.

Ideally I'd like the default value to be the Schedule DateTime

Comment: You should be able to reference the scheduled time the trigger fires using `@trigger().scheduledTime`. Pass then into your pipeline as a parameter. An example can be found in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger#pass-the-trigger-start-time-to-a-pipeline).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as Kyle Bunting says, you can create a parameter and it's default value is `@trigger().scheduledTime` like this:

[image]

Then ADF will pass scheduled time of trigger to your parameter in top level pipeline.

My test result:
[image]